# Can logadm include the date in the filename?

Tags: solaris, logging

I'd prefer for logadm to name files with a YYYYMMDD extensions, instead of the standard .0, .1, .2 ...  I'd still want log admin to keep the last 'n' log rotations.

Is this possible, or am using the wrong tool for application log rotation?  I'm rotating files only based on date, and not by size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep the last 10  rotations with YYYYMMDD extensions:

```
logadm -c 10 -t '$file.%Y%m%d' /path/to/file
```

See also the [logadm](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1462/logadm-1m.html) and [strftime](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1465/strftime-3c.html) manpages.

Comment: The *logadmin* link is broken, the good one is here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-0211/816-0211.pdf